# docker-compose up : Encountered errors while bringing up the project

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I am working on Ubuntu Mint 17.2 64-bit and installed Docker using installation guide.
Getting problem while `docker-compose up`.

When fire command it shows me error like :

```
data is up-to-date
db is up-to-date
Starting web

ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: oci runtime error: exec: "./entrypoint.sh": stat ./entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Here version info:

```
docker --version
Docker version 1.6.2

docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.8.0

docker-machine --version
docker-machine version 0.7.0
```

`docker-compose.yml` look like

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        restart: always
        container_name: nginx
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes_from:
            - web
        links:
            - web:web

    web:
        restart: always
        container_name: web
        build: .
        expose:
            - "8000"
        env_file: .env
        volumes:
            - ./web:/web
        links:
            - db:db
        depends_on:
            - db
        command: ./entrypoint.sh
...
```

I think in web `entrypoint.sh` was not found,
For more info also give permission in `Dockerfile` file,In it `RUN chmod +x /web/entrypoint.sh`

I am not sure how to solve this issue.

**Edit**:

I am connect docker-machine with ssh and find web dir empty.

Comment: What happens if you set entrypoint as the full path, i.e. `entrypoint: /web/entrypoint.sh`

Comment: @jedifans It shows same error with `/web/entrypoint.sh` no such file or directory

Comment: Can you add the Dockerfile for the web-container?

Comment: @mgansler web was project root so in it `entrypoint.sh` , `manage.py` and other stuf.

Comment: @JayminSuthar try command: sh entrypoint.sh (I assume that entrypoint.sh is in the same dir as the docker-compose.yml)

Comment: @artworkadシ entrypoine.sh and docker-compose.yml is not in same dir.
entrypoint.sh is in web dir.

And docker-compose.yml is it in project root

Comment: @JayminSuthar okay, still try command: sh /whatever/dir/entrypoint.sh

Comment: @artworkadシ I'm tried with `command: sh /whatever/dir/entrypoint.sh` but still it return `web      |  sh: 0: Can't open`

Comment: @JayminSuthar try command: bash -c "sh /path/to/entrypoint.sh"

Comment: Are you sure you have `entrypoint.sh` in your host `web` folder?

Comment: @dieend Yes I'm sure `entrypoint.sh` is in `web` folder, But when connect using `docker-machine ssh <machine_name>` web folder shows me empty.

Comment: try to update docker to the current version 1.12

Comment: @Ohmen already docker machine work on 1.2 : `api  *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.12.1   
`

Comment: please provide `docker version`

Comment: @Ohmen Here output of `docker --version` : `Docker version 1.12.1, build`.

Comment: ok. start the container with a shell and go to the location where you expect the entrypoint script. I suspect it just does not have corect permissions.

Comment: @Ohmen I'm tried to connect web cintainer with shell using `docker exec -it d52092d6be76fb6d04fe99049968cf048da6e3f10d0fdc42165b67334d05ea37 bash` but it shows me `Error response from daemon: Container d52092d6be76fb6d04fe99049968cf048da6e3f10d0fdc42165b67334d05ea37 is not running`

Comment: build and run the container manually and then simly do `docker run -it yourImage bash`. then navigate to the entrypoint

Comment: @Ohmen I'm build and run container and found dirs and file which expected. For more info fire command `ls -al` and output was `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  264 Aug 23 07:12 entrypoint.sh`

Comment: hmm to bad ... my last idea build it manualy with `--no-cache`. If this does not work im out of Ideas

Comment: @Ohmen I'm tried build with  `--no-cache` since last two days, BTW Thank you for give me you time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker-machine` only creates shared folders for `/home`. If the project is not under the home directory then you wont be able to use volumes.

You can either add another shared folder,or move the project. Since you are on linux you don't actually need to use `docker-machine`, you could just use docker directly on the host.

Answer (score 4):

run command
docker rm -f somecontainer

and then restart docker, run the same command again solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error "docker-compose up : Encountered errors while bringing up the project" occurred because there was not enough space for the docker containers. So my colleague suggested me the following steps :
Step 1 : `df -h` to check the available space
Step 2 : `docker image ls` to check where the maximum containers are eating up the space.
Step 3 : Remove the **unnecessary** space by `docker image prune`
Then try `docker-compose up` and see if it works.
Hope this helped !